# Anoymous ip route on my server

Tags: linux, debian, ip, routing

After typing "route -n" on my server, i figured out these lines

```
1.0.104.156     -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
1.9.22.84       -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
1.9.27.129      -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
1.9.63.206      -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
1.9.116.134     -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
1.9.123.225     -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
```

to

```
223.203.194.5   -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
223.203.218.68  -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
223.203.218.91  -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
223.206.106.124 -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
223.222.241.34  -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
223.224.126.254 -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
223.239.223.254 -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
223.255.162.34  -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
223.255.165.226 -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
223.255.183.202 -               255.255.255.255 !H        - -          - -
```

total : 42727 lines

Where might that come from and how to know?

Comment: Where are you based? These addresses are all based in the far east. Japan, Malaysia & China. Do you do business there?

Comment: is the exit interface for these routes different from your default gateway?

Comment: @JulianKnight France, but there is other IP from USA, Poland, Denmark..

Comment: @FrankThomas yes

Comment: That doesn't look at all right unless you know that your server should be talking to these locations, you need to take some urgent remedial action. Have you checked what processes are running? Are you running IPTABLES? Have you configured it? Have you checked logins? Logs?

Comment: @JulianKnight I checked the log, logins, process, scanned with Clamav and everything seems ok, i have an empty iptables without any rules

Comment: Its hard to tell much more without seeing the unredacted route table, but I'd block the gateway these connections are using outbound until you get it figured out.

Comment: Empty IPTABLES! Maybe therein lies the problem. You need to get a secure setup into IPTABLES asap. Block all incoming except specifically what you need and block all outgoing similarly. While you are at it, install FAIL2BAN which will add some smarts to help stop anyone gaining access.

Answer (score 0):

In the hope that this may be of assistance, here is a copy of an IPTABLES ruleset that should be reasonably secure but still allow access to standard and some non-standard services:

```
*filter

# Reject some specifics (picked up from logs & fail2ban)
# -A INPUT -s 213.239.213.102 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables DROP: " --log-level 7
# -A INPUT -s 213.239.213.102 -j REJECT
# -A INPUT -s 208.76.245.135 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables DROP: " --log-level 7
# -A INPUT -s 208.76.245.135 -j REJECT
-A INPUT -s 78.189.110.91 -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables DROP: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -s 78.189.110.91 -j REJECT


#  Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

#  Accepts all established inbound connections
# This is best:
#-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# But the extension might not be available so may need to use this:
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#  Allows all outbound traffic
#  You can modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

# Allows HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites)
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
# Allow non-standard http(s) connections for Node.js etc
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5050:5151 -j ACCEPT

#  Allows SSH connections (on non-standard port <1024)
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 444 -j ACCEPT

#  Allows mail connections
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 585 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 995 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# log iptables denied calls
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables DENY: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT

# ----------------------------------------------------
#  NAT Rules
# ----------------------------------------------------
*nat

:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

COMMIT
*mangle
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed
```

Note that this version is not blocking outbound but it would be best to do so. Also, if you don't need your server to have access to/from some of those networks, simply block them 1.9.*.*, etc. At least for a while.